# Why is the armature current constant in a field controlled DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor

I'm studying DC motors.  When I got to field control DC motors I realized that one of the premises might be unaccurate.

In DC motors, the  magnetic flux is proportional to field current, back EMF is proportional to flux and angular velocity and the armature current is dependant on the  armature voltage (which remains constant) and back EMF.  this made me think that in field control DC motors, armature current is not constant:

$$\Phi(t) \propto i_f(t)$$
$$EMF(t) \propto \Phi(t),\omega(t)$$
$$EMF(t) =k_m\cdot \Phi(t) \cdot \omega(t) =  k_m\cdot k_e \cdot i_f(t) \cdot \omega(t)$$

$$I_a(s) = \frac{E_a(s)-EMF(s)}{s\cdot L_a+R_a}$$

How could armature current be constant if speed or field current change?

Comment: Armature current is never assumed to be a constant, either in fixed field or controlled field motors. Come up with a better assumption.

Comment: As far as i know, it's the main assumption of controlled field DC motors the constant armature current. Check out this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P__9WMe31VI

There are many videos like that doing that assumption, and it's the same as my teacher from college did.

Comment: There's a maximum safe current, given by heating. We often calculate what happens at the limit, assuming everyone knows that there will be less of it below the limit. In a controlled field motor, output torque is proportional to field x armature current. Constant torque loads are a common assumption, for instance a crane lifting a load, and cranes is one of the archetypal applications of series DC machines.